# "We could unload the boat faster by making a ___ line."

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

My old PE teacher had us do an activity where we had to pass items down a chain of students (balls, sandbags, etc). There is a word for it.

A line of people used to move a lot of things quickly, like sandbags in a flood situation.

I used to hear it fairly regularly, but I cannot remember what it is now.

It is NOT 'human chain', 'bucket brigade', or 'relay'.

Comment: Was it “chain gang”?

Comment: It’s *Citizen Kane*…

Comment: ... by making a conga line.

Answer (score 3):

While you discard this term, I think the most common name for it is a **relay line**:

> So the cadet moving the sandbags down the **relay line** would call out what they were passing on, saying "heavy, light, leaky bag" to warn the next in line of what was headed their way, even saying "it's bleeding" for a bag that was losing all integrity.
> [image]
> Image: Cadet 2nd Class Zach Mattee hands a leaking sandbag to Cadet 3rd Class Steve Kearney Sept. 30, 2011, in Pierre, S.D., as the cadets removed sandbags from levees as part of flood relief and cleanup
>
> — [Cadets perform flood relief work in South Dakota](https://www.usafa.af.mil/News/News-Display/Article/428645/cadets-perform-flood-relief-work-in-south-dakota/)

Another example:

> The next week, once the ditches had been dug and the small barrier walls were in place, we filled the sidewalk area with concrete and smoothed it out. The only way we could make this process easy was to form a **relay line**. One pan of concrete at a time had to be passed from person to person until it reached the end, where it was dumped into place and the Nepali mason used a 2×4 and a trowel to smooth it evenly.
>
> — [Week Twelve and Thirteen](http://lumos.belmont.edu/week-twelve-and-thirteen-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9/)

---

I've also seen it described using the name of whatever is being passed:

> [Men working a **bucket line** at the Ophir Saloon fire, Council, December 30, 1904](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Men_working_a_bucket_line_at_the_Ophir_Saloon_fire,_Council,_December_30,_1904_(AL%2BCA_102).jpg)

> Fisher High School students Morgan Bregier, left, and Evelyn Drengson work a **sandbag line** as the Red Lake River rises in the background on Monday, April 25, 2022.
> — [Grand Forks-area students jump in to help fight region's rising waters](https://www.grandforksherald.com/weather/grand-forks-area-students-jump-in-to-help-fight-regions-rising-waters)

Comment: The OP says *"It is NOT 'human chain', 'bucket brigade', or '**relay**'."

Comment: @Greybeard Well, maybe they misremembered. The purpose of the site is not to guess what someone's PE teacher called it; it's to answer questions about English, and "relay line" is a good answer.

Comment: @Greybeard - https://youtu.be/PFZDrOCLX2Y

Comment: @ColleenV *"relay line" is a good answer.* It is an excellent answer - it is the phrase that I would use. However, the OP is apparently looking for the word that his old PE teacher used, and the OP specifically excludes "relay".

Comment: @Greybeard And that is the problem with single word requests. I’m looking for a word that starts with ‘p’ and has two syllables that describes something that requires some ingenuity to solve, but it’s not “puzzle”. Guessing at a vague recollection of something someone said that may or may not have been the correct word is not what this site is for. We’re not here to jog one person’s memory.